# Internet Explorer 9 Gradient Filter Cuts Off Submenu

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a strange problem with Internet Explorer 9. The CSS Filter Gradient used cuts off my submenu. For example, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16qchfc6/7/). Below is a simple code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="headWrapper">
    <header>
        <nav id="main">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Parent Navigation Item</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>           
        </nav><!-- main -->
    </header>
</div><!-- headWrapper -->
```

**CSS**

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
header, nav     {display: block;}
#headWrapper    {border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; position: relative; z-index: 5; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e1eaf0',GradientType=0 );}
header          {width: 1000px; height: 75px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both;}

#main                   {float: left;}
#main ul                {list-style: none;}
#main li                {float: left;}
#main a                 {display: block;}
#main li ul.submenu         {display: block; padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #000; position: absolute; z-index: 999; border: 1px solid #ddd; margin-left: 12px; border-top: 0; background-color: beige; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;}
#main li ul.submenu li      {float: none; display: block;}
```

If I remove the filter gradient from my `#headWrapper` my menu works as expected. With the gradient in there I can only view the border and it cuts off anything past the headers actual height.

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I go about fixing it?

I've tested it via IE Emulated and [Browser Shots](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/) and it shows up broken in both so it seems like it's not just an emulator issue (or Browser Shots is using an emulator and just showing me what I already know). I've been playing around with it for an hour and have had no luck fixing it unless I remove the gradient entirely OR remove the fixed / z-index which I also do not want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4g15ya2w/1/)

You can separate the div that will have this background from the tag that will hold the links. Here's what I mean in more details:

`<div id="headWrapper">` should not be the parent of all the text because it will restrict it's height after using the filter in the internet explorer. (This seems to be a common problem and it forces the overflow to be hidden).

Therefore, just place the `<div id="headWrapper"></div>` as a sibling of your header tag and make both headWrapper and header to have a fixed position:

```
#headWrapper {... position: fixed; ...}
header {... position: fixed; ...}
```

and here's how the html looks like (Check my comment):

```
<div>
    <div id="headWrapper"></div>
    <!--Notice the headWrapper and header are siblings-->
    <header>
        <nav id="main">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Parent Navigation Item</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Child Nav Item 6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>           
        </nav><!-- main -->
    </header>
</div>
```

Please note that I've also made some random improvements to your CSS:

```
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {height: 1000px;}

#headWrapper    {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e1eaf0',GradientType=0 );
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
    position: fixed;
    height:75px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

header { width: 100%; position:fixed; }

#main {float:left;}
#main ul li a { float:left; width:100%; }
#main li ul.submenu {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd; 
    margin-left: 12px; 
    border-top: 0; 
    background-color: beige;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; 
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}
```

**Alternative solution:**

Make the gradient effect as a background image and repeat it horizontally. 

Demo from [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-repeatx)

Answer (score 0):

by removing the z-index from #headWrapper it will work

```
#headWrapper {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*z-index: 5;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e1eaf0',GradientType=0 );
}
```

you can check here [**Full Screen JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/16qchfc6/12/show/)

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/16qchfc6/12/)

check this issue on ie 9

[Z-index or overflow issue, on a css menu, with gradient background in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780124/z-index-or-overflow-issue-on-a-css-menu-with-gradient-background-in-ie-9)

Comment: Yeah but removing the Z-Index could potentially allow things to be positioned over the header since the header is Fixed.

Comment: or you can use gradient background-image for #headWrapper which will work in all the browsers

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a separate element as well, but making it not sibling of the actual container, but its child element:

```
<div id="headWrapper">
    <div id="headerDummy"></div>
    <header>
        ...
    </header>
</div>
```

`#headerDummy` will play as a gradient holder, and we can make it stretch to fill the whole parent:

```
#headerDummy{

    /* The bacgkground-serving el will not interfere the normal flow, ... */
    position:absolute;

    /* ... it will have exactly the same size, as the container (you can make it taller or wider and don't have to change the #headerDummy style), ... */
    top:0;              
    left:0;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    /* ... be BEHIND the actual content... */
    z-index:1;

    /* ... and still have our gradient. */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endC
olorstr='#e1eaf0',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Everything that remains is telling the content to be **above** the background, that way:

```
header{
    position:relativer;
    z-index:10;
    ...
}
```

This is how it will look: http://jsfiddle.net/16qchfc6/22/

We could make it even better and more semantically correct by using a pseudo-element instead of an actual element, but unfortunately [IE seems not to apply filter for pseudo-elelemnts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669986/1825533)

---

By the way, the actual live IE9 on Win7 shows the menu like this:

[image]

Taking the fact, that the border is not cropped, so it might be just a bug or some kind of bag algorythm piece.